# Decision tree classifier

Tags: classification

I have seen weka j48 classifier, I want to build a classifier similar to it but I don't know how to go about it. 
Can anyone advice me on how to create a classifier algorithm for decision tree?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm

Comment: I kindly request you to go through the community question guidelines,hope in near future you will contribute to the human civilisation.

Comment: Read Ross Quinlan's book "C4.5: Programs for Machine Learning (Morgan Kaufmann Series in Machine Learning)".

Comment: What language are you planning to use?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open source implementations of the C4.5 algorithm invented by Ross Quinlan:

- Java: https://github.com/scottjulian/C4.5
- Python: https://github.com/dpkravi/DecisionTreeClassifier
- C++: https://github.com/zgyao/DecisionTree_C4.5
- JavaScript: https://github.com/miguelmota/C4.5